# How can I communicate user information from a website to a hosted Unity game?

Tags: unity

I have a Ruby on Rails website running which provides a log-in system and dashboard for users. I am building a small game in Unity which is much like an inventory management system. But, the inventory is specific to a user and the user can make changes to it. The user sees the game as a part of *his* dashboard.

What I'd like is for the moment the user lands on his dashboard, the Unity game should load with the inventory of the signed-in user. How can I get this user information from the Ruby dashboard over to Unity?

Comment: This is purely guess-work as I have not tested it, but it *might* be possible to attach a C# script to a game object and in that script's void start() method make a web request to your website/service with a System.Net.Http.HttpClient() to get details of the signed-in user's inventory. Assuming the player also signs into the game too and you use oAuth tokens or similar to authenticate the player making the request from your game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is asking how to know which user has loaded the webplayer. (If not, please provide more details.)

Unity can communicate arbitrarily with the browser and vice versa via JavaScript (details and examples [here in the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)).

On app startup you can request this data from within Unity with `Application.ExternalCall()`, by calling to a function in the browser that will in turn run (javascript) `UnityObject2.getUnity().SendMessage(...)` to transfer the information back to Unity. These messages can be used to tell Unity which user is logged in and, if you choose, the needed authentication information.

With this, you should have all the information you need to request that user's inventory from your server. Displaying/updating it after that should be straightforward.